# A very long boolean array/std::bitset

Tags: c++, boolean

For some C++ code, my logic requires a boolean array containing 4*10^10 indices. I am using the STL container `std::bitset`. But its implementation as `template < size_t N > class bitset;` restricts the number of bits to the upper limit of the `size_t` (unsigned integral type) data type, which is 2^32-1 (or 2^64-1) {**Can someone confirm this as well**}.

I thought of a workaround for this issue by creating an `array of bitset`, as in `bitset<100000000> checkSum[400]`;

Is this legal? I am getting the following compilation error (test.cpp is my C++ file)

```
/tmp/cc0gR0c6.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
test.cpp:(.text+0x35f): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32 against `.bss'
test.cpp:(.text+0x373): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32 against `.bss'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can this somehow be fixed or is there a better workaround?

Comment: That array needs more than 4GB of static data. If you're on Windows, I think you can get no more than 2GB of memory for it. Try allocating it dynamically (even that won't work if you're on 32bit system).

Comment: @jrok Yes, it seems you are right. Can't allocate 4GB of memory. Will work on a better logic to avoid this.

Comment: If this is a contest or programming puzzle, the problem is probably based around blocking the naive solution by making the data 10 times to big to fit in memory on the test system.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use vector instead of array,just like:

```
vector<bitset<1000000> > checkSum;
```

Comment: `std::vector<bitset<10^7> > checkSum(400, bitset<maxArraySize> ());` works fine. But note that it only allocates 4*10^9.
`std::vector<bitset<10^7> > checkSum(4000, bitset<maxArraySize> ());` results in the runtime error `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)
`

Comment: I think memory is not enough,10^7 bits need 1M memory,4000*10^7 almost need 4G,maybe you do not have enough memory!

Answer (score 0):

size_t is either 32 or 64 bits, depending whether you're compiling 32 or 64 bit code.  It looks like you can simply compile for a 64 bit target and solve this.

Comment: My machine is 64 bit and `bitset<3*10^10>` works fine but `bitset<4*10^10>` gives the same compile error as mentioned in the question. Also, I guess the online judge to which I am submitting my code is 32 bit; hence a workaround is required.